# Angular - How to make Angular Material Validate on Next Button

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have this code in my Angular-11 project where I used Material-Stepper:

I have the typescript.

registration.component.ts:

```js
export class SignupComponent implements OnInit {
  isLinear = true;
  isLoading = false;
  isSubmitted = false;
  companyInfoForm!: FormGroup;
  userInfoForm!: FormGroup;

  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private api: ApiService,
    private token: TokenService,
    private router: Router,
    private toastr: ToastrService,
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.createCompany();
  }

  headers = { //Token for API Authorization
    'Authorization': this.token.get(),
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
  }
  createCompany() {

    this.companyInfoForm = this.fb.group({
      name: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(100)]],
    });
    this.userInfoForm = this.fb.group({
      first_name: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(50)]],
      last_name: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(50)]],
      email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
      password: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6)]],
      confirm_password: ['', [Validators.required]],
    }, {
      validator: MustMatch('password', 'confirm_password')
    });
  }

  onSubmit() {
    this.isSubmitted = true;

    if (this.companyInfoForm.invalid) {
      return;
    }
    if (this.userInfoForm.invalid) {
      return;
    }

    const formCompanyData = this.companyInfoForm.getRawValue();
    const formUserData = this.userInfoForm.getRawValue();

    const data = {
      name: formCompanyData.name,
      first_name: formUserData.first_name,
      last_name: formUserData.last_name,
      email: formUserData.email,
      password: formUserData.password,
      confirm_password: formUserData.confirm_password,
    };

    const header = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    };
    this.isLoading = true;
    return this.api.post('register', data, header)
      .pipe(first())
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          this.tokenHandler(data);
        }
  
  tokenHandler(data: any) {
      Swal.fire({
        position: 'center',
        icon: 'success',
        title: data.message,
        showConfirmButton: true,
        timer: 5000
      });
      this.router.navigateByUrl('/auth');
    }
  }
}
```

Then I have the registration HTML

registration.component.html:

```html
<mat-horizontal-stepper [linear]="isLinear" #stepper labelPosition="bottom">
  <mat-step [stepControl]="companyInfoForm">
    <form [formGroup]="companyInfoForm">
      <ng-template matStepLabel>Company Info</ng-template>
      <div class="card-body">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="name">Company Name:<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
              <input type="text" formControlName="name" placeholder="Company Name" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <mat-error *ngIf="companyInfoForm.controls['name'].hasError('required')">
              Company Name is required!
            </mat-error>
            <mat-error *ngIf="companyInfoForm.controls['name'].hasError('maxlength')">
              Company Name cannot be more than 100 characters!
            </mat-error>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <button mat-raised-button color="primary" matStepperNext>Next</button>
        </div>
    </form>
  </mat-step>
  <mat-step [stepControl]="userInfoForm">
    <form [formGroup]="userInfoForm">
      <ng-template matStepLabel>User Info</ng-template>
      <div class="card-body">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="first_name">First Nme:<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
              <input type="text" formControlName="first_name" placeholder="First Name" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <mat-error *ngIf="userInfoForm.controls['first_name'].hasError('required')">
              First Name is required!
            </mat-error>
            <mat-error *ngIf="userInfoForm.controls['first_name'].hasError('maxlength')">
              First Name cannot be more than 50 characters!
            </mat-error>
          </div>
          <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="last_name">Last Name:<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
              <input type="text" formControlName="last_name" placeholder="Last Name" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <mat-error *ngIf="userInfoForm.controls['last_name'].hasError('required')">
              Last Name is required!
            </mat-error>
            <mat-error *ngIf="userInfoForm.controls['last_name'].hasError('maxlength')">
              Last Name cannot be more than 50 characters!
            </mat-error>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="password">Password:<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
              <input type="password" formControlName="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <mat-error *ngIf="userInfoForm.controls['password'].hasError('required')">
              Password is required!
            </mat-error>
            <mat-error *ngIf="userInfoForm.controls['password'].hasError('minlength')">
              Password cannot be less than 6 characters!
            </mat-error>
          </div>
          <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="confirm_password">Confirm Password:<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
              <input type="password" formControlName="confirm_password" placeholder="Confirm Password" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <mat-error *ngIf="userInfoForm.controls['confirm_password'].hasError('required')">
              Confirm Password is required!
            </mat-error>
            <mat-error *ngIf="userInfoForm.controls['confirm_password'].hasError('MustMatch')">
              Passwords must match!
            </mat-error>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="email">Email:<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
              <input type="email" formControlName="email" placeholder="Email" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <mat-error *ngIf="userInfoForm.controls['email'].hasError('required')">
              Password is required!
            </mat-error>
            <mat-error *ngIf="userInfoForm.controls['email'].hasError('email')">
              Email must be a valid email address!
            </mat-error>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button mat-raised-button color="black" matStepperPrevious>Back</button>&nbsp;
        <button mat-raised-button color="primary" matStepperNext>Next</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </mat-step>
  <mat-step>
    <ng-template matStepLabel>Review</ng-template>
    <h5>You are now done.</h5>
    <div>
      <button mat-raised-button color="black" matStepperPrevious>Back</button> &nbsp;
      <button mat-raised-button color="success" [disabled]="isLoading" type="submit">
                  <span *ngIf="isLoading" class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm mr-1"></span>
                    Submit
                </button> &nbsp;
      <button mat-raised-button color="warn" (click)="stepper.reset()">Reset</button>
    </div>
  </mat-step>

</mat-horizontal-stepper>
```

I observe that when the form loads, the validation for required for each stepper shows (especially required validation) without clicking the next button.

I want the validation validation to only take effect when the Next button is onClick.

How do I achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Hello. Any help on this, so that validation validation for required will not appear by default until when the Next button on the stepper is clicked. Thanks in advance